# Why I Can't import CSS/JS code in an error page using django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've a custom error_page in my django app that I call when something got wrong. The problem is when I try to load my 'base.html' or anything related to javascript, CSS, or python code I got errors like:

```
ValueError: The file 'style.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff3b288d9d0>.
```

Here my code:

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.conf.urls import handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500

handler500 = main_views.server_error
```

**MAIN_VIEWS.PY**

```
def server_error(request):
    return render (request, 'error_page.html', status=500)
```

**ERROR_PAGE.HTML**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% block head_title %}Error Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
     $.get("{% url 'home_page' %}") // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
<script/>

<h1><b>AN ERROR OCURRED! THIS PAGE DOESN'T EXISTS OR COULDN'T BE FIND! YOU WILL BE REDIRECTED TO HOME PAGE IN 5 SECONDS...</b></h1>

{% endblock content %}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` before running the server with `DEBUG=False`

Also, in your `settins.py` you should have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: I've already did all you posted and didn't work. Have you another suggestion?